# "Wrong Application" is displayed in phone

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mobile, installation

I have some kind of wiered situation. I built an android app with version 2.3.3. This runs with no issue in eclipse. But, when I put it into a device, I can't open it because it is a "wrong application". "Wrong Application" is displayed just above the name of my android app in phone's installation manager.

Why I am getting this kind of issue?

**edit**

Since a member asked for a photo, I took a one with my laptop webcam. Sorry it is not clear but readable. I have surrounded the app with red border

[image]

Comment: Care to post a screenshot ?

Comment: @MiklosAubert: This is happening in the real device. So I can't get a screenshot

Comment: Depending on the device, it should be possible. Try pressing Power + Home (lightly press Power and immediately press Home). Works on my phone.

Comment: @MiklosAubert: I took a one with my laptop

Comment: You can capture your device's screen using the Android DDMS <http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html>. With that you should get a pretty good picture that helps us to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the phone. This worked perfectly on HP Slate 7